# Parse string in C with sscanf

Tags: c

The string I am trying to parse is called str1, and it contains `PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"`

The goal is to have one variable contain `PRETTY_NAME`, and the other contains `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`. I have declared both variables as `char *var1, *var2`

This has to be done with the sscanf function in C.

My current code looks like: `sscanf(str1, "%s[^=]^s", var1. var2);` The output I am receiving is that both var1, and var2 return `(null)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That line can not possibly compile. Please post real code, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `char *catch_str;` That's an uninitialized pointer, so `sscanf(str1, "%s %s", catch_str, ...);` is undefined behavior. Either change it to `char catch_str[100];` or allocate it dynamically. Same goes for `my_str`, then after that you'll still have to fix the `sscanf` format string.

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide any hints as to what I am doing wrong with my sscanf format?

Comment: You probably want something like `"%[^=]=\"%[^\"]\""`. Don't forget to check the return value of `sscanf` to make sure that parsing succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

the `%s` matches the entire string terminates at white space or `\0` including `=` in that case, you can't use that here, and you haven't initialized any of your char buffer with a size which leads to crash or undefined behavior. here is a simplified parser.

```c
void parse(const char* str, char* pretty, char* release) {
    int pretty_end, start, end;
    sscanf(str, "%*[^=]%n=\"%n%*[^\"]%n\"", &pretty_end, &start, &end);
    
    strncpy(pretty, str, pretty_end);
    pretty[pretty_end] = '\0';
    
    strncpy(release, str+start, end-start);
    release[end - start] = '\0';
}

int main() {

    const char* str = "PRETTY_NAME=\"Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS\"";
    char pretty[256];
    char release[256];
    parse(str, pretty, release);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice use of `"%n"`, yet better to first `end = 0` and test after `sscanf()`  that it is not zero before using `pretty_end, start, end`.